# NSString, NSMutableString memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Here I have 2 string objects

```
    NSString *name1 = @"Julia";
    NSString *name2 = @"Julia";

    NSLog(@"name1's memory: %p and name2's memory: %p", name1, name2);
```

These are 2 objects, because the content is exactly same, it automatically points to the same memory.

This is the log

```
    name1's memory: 0x100002320 and name2's memory: 0x100002320
```

This same behavior also exists in Java Programming Language.

Next, I do the same test with NSMutableString.

```
    NSString *name1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Julia"];
    NSString *name2 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Julia"];

    NSLog(@"name1's memory: %p and name2's memory: %p", name1, name2);
```

This is the log

```
    name1's memory: 0x10010a4c0 and name2's memory: 0x10010a550
```

The results are different. Each of it points to its own memory.

How do you explain this? Is the NSString more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this contrived example, you could get the same performance from:

```
NSString *name1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Julia"];
NSString *name2 = name1;
```

But yes immutable strings will attempt to get better performance by pointing to the same memory addresses when possible, obviously this can't happen with mutable strings, since modifying one should not change some other arbitrary string that was pointing to the same memory for efficiency.  For most cases the mutable string is going to be more efficient, but sure in this contrived example the immutable string would be more efficient in terms of memory space.